# Jquery valildator not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently found [this](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validating-australian-abn-numbers) page showing a jquery validator function for an australian business number. in my Cshtml page I have the following form element.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ABN" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <input asp-for="ABN" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ABN" class="text-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have placed the jquery code into the page and using the F12 debugger I note that it does step through it but while its a number that returns false I get nothing happening regarding an error.. the page just goes off to update the DB.

```
function abnValidate (value, element) {
    if (value.length != 11 || isNaN(parseInt(value)))
    return false;
    var weighting = [10,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19];
    var tally = (parseInt(value[0]) - 1) * weighting[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < value.length; i++) {
        tally += (parseInt(value[i]) * weighting[i]);
    }
    return (tally % 89) == 0;
}
jQuery.validator.addMethod('abnValidate', abnValidate, 'This ABN is not valid');
```

I have tried it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/si2030/yu41xvvu/) but all I get is the error:

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

I suspect this is a case of not knowing how to correctly configure the code. Could someone have a look and see what I am missing?

EDIT

Here is the full form as requested.

```
            @model JobsLedger.ViewModels.CompanyDetailsViewModel

        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <br />
            <div class="form-horizontal container">


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                        <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit Company Details </h2>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="CompanyDetailsId" />


                @*ROW ONE*@
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="CompanyName" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                <input asp-for="CompanyName" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="CompanyName" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                @*ROW TWO*@
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="ContactFirstName" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                <input asp-for="ContactFirstName" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="ContactFirstName" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="ContactLastName" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                <input asp-for="ContactLastName" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="ContactLastName" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                @*ROW THREE*@
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="ContactEmail" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                <input asp-for="ContactEmail" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="ContactEmail" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>

                @*ROW FOUR*@
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="MobilePhone" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                <input asp-for="MobilePhone" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="MobilePhone" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="OfficePhone" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                <input asp-for="OfficePhone" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="OfficePhone" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


                @*ROW FIVE*@
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="CompanyEmail" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                <input asp-for="CompanyEmail" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="CompanyEmail" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                @*ROW SIX*@
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="ABN" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                <input asp-for="ABN" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="ABN" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><strong>Company Address Details</strong></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        @*ROW SEVEN*@
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="Street1" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                        <input asp-for="Street1" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Street1" class="text-danger" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="Street2" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                        <input asp-for="Street2" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Street2" class="text-danger" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        @*ROW EIGHT*@
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="State" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                        <select asp-for="State" asp-items="@Model.StatesList" class="form-control"></select>
                                        <span asp-validation-for="State" class="text-danger" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="Suburb" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                        <input asp-for="Suburb" class="form-control">
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Suburb" class="text-danger" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="Postcode" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                        <input asp-for="Postcode" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Postcode" class="text-danger" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><strong>Company Bank Details</strong></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        @*ROW NINE*@
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="BankName" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                        <input asp-for="BankName" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="BankName" class="text-danger" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="BankBSB" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                        <input asp-for="BankBSB" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="BankBSB" class="text-danger" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="BankAccount" class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                        <input asp-for="BankAccount" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="BankAccount" class="text-danger" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                @*ROW TEN*@
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label">Update Form:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                @*Closing DIV for class horizontal*@

            </div>

        </form>

        <div>
            <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
        </div>

        @section Scripts {
            <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>


            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                $(document).ready(function () {



                    function abnValidate(value, element) {
                        if (value.length != 11 || isNaN(parseInt(value)))
                            return false;
                        var weighting =
                        [10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19];
                        var tally = (parseInt(value[0]) - 1) * weighting[0];
                        for (var i = 1; i < value.length; i++) {
                            tally += (parseInt(value[i]) * weighting[i]);
                        }
                        return (tally % 89) == 0;
                    }
                    jQuery.validator.addMethod(
                    'abnValidate',
                    $("#ABN"), 'This ABN is not valid'
                    );


                });

                //]]></script>

        }
```

Comment: Can we see the full form?

Comment: Can you check the console for other errors. I believe some other javascript is failing and form is getting posted. Make sure all the validations returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example it is not really clear, where and or if you are actually calling the validate method on the above form. You are using a custom added method with which you presumably want to validate the form-filed `<input type="text" name="abnValidate" />`. Your custom method needs to return `true` for the `abnValidate` field to be valid. If the method returns `false`, it should return the message you've put up as the third argument to `addMethod`.

> [**jQuery.validator.addMethod()**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)
>
> **Description**: Add a custom validation method. It must consist of a name (must be a legal javascript identifier), a javascript based function and a default string message.
>
> **method**
>   Type: Function()
>   The actual method implementation, returning true if an element is valid. First argument: Current value. Second argument: Validated element. Third argument: Parameters.

The other thing is how are you planning to send your form data. The validate plugin will not send the form for you. It will just validate the fields you tell it to validate by defining specific rules which associates an element with a validation method. Since you did not provide any attributes to the form element which would define the HTTP method to be used to send the form with or the URI which should take care of processing the form data, makes it hard to tell what you are up to. You do not have to provide the form with the information to use the validate plugin.

The `validate` method has a `submitHandler` option which is a callback to handle the actual form submit, which will be called if the form is valid.

> **submitHandler**(default: native form submit)
>
> Type: Function()
>   Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated.

As you can tell from the docs you could just use the `submitHandler` to send the form data via ajax or do any other optimization to your form data.

To make a long story short.
Here is an example of what this could look like.
Hope it helps.

```js
$(function() {

  // Your custom validation method added to the validate plugin
  jQuery.validator.addMethod( 'abnValidate', function abnValidate(value, element) {
    if (value.length != 11 || isNaN(parseInt(value)))
      return false;
    var weighting =
        [10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19];
    var tally = (parseInt(value[0]) - 1) * weighting[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < value.length; i++) {
      tally += (parseInt(value[i]) * weighting[i]);
    }
    return (tally % 89) == 0;
  }, 'This ABN is not valid');

  // call the validate method on your form element.
  $(".validation-form").validate({
    debug: true,
    // define a rule for the form field which will make use of your abnValidate method.
    rules: {
      "abnValidate": {
        abnValidate: true,
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      // 'form' is your form element being validated, do somethig with it.

      var data = $(form).serializeArray();
      console.log(data);
      
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form class="validation-form">
    <input type="text" name="abnValidate" />
    <button class="submit-form">submit</button>
</form>

<div class="form-status">form not yet submitted</div>
```

Comment: Thanks David.. I am not sure what I need to do with the submitHandler.  My final intention is to convert this to a custom taghelper (after of course getting it to work) so the intention was not to interfere with the form submit ie not do it by ajax.. and to highlight errors on the page. That being said there were no errors in the console..

Comment: You do not need to use the submitHandler, just provide the form element with the appropriate attributes on how you want to send the form and you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the following somewhere

```
<form method="POST">
```